# SailsJS 0.10.1 with sails-rest

Tags: sails.js

I am trying to use SailsJS 0.10.1 to talk with an existing backend API and render pages with that content. I am running into issues with getting the sails-rest adapter to work properly, I can define the connection in connections.js and hard code a resource and then find works. What I want is to have the model name as the resource or be able to specify the resource in a config parameter at the model level.

## Model

```
/**
* Product.js
*
* @description :: TODO: You might write a short summary of how this model works and what it       represents here.
* @docs        :: http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/models
*/

module.exports = {

};
```

## Controller

```
index: function(req, res ,next){
    var options = {
      limit: req.param('limit') || undefined
    };

    Product.find(options, function(err, product){

      if (product === 'undefined') return res.notFound();
      if (err) return next(err);
      res.view('products/index', { products: product });
    });
  }
```

## Connections

```
rest: {
      adapter: 'sails-rest',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3000,               // api port
      protocol: 'http',         // HTTP protocol (http | https)
      pathname: null,           // base api path
      resource: null,           // resource path to use (overrides model name)
      action: null,             // action to use for the given resource ([resource]/run)
      query: {},                // query parameters to provide with all GET requests
      methods: {                // overrides default HTTP methods used for each CRUD action
          create: 'post',
          find: 'get',
          update: 'put',
          destroy: 'del'
      }
  }
```

Comment: You've posted some code, but you need to be clear as to the actual problem you're experiencing (what are the expected vs. actual results?)

Comment: When I use `Product.find(options, function...` I am expecting to make a call to the backend. When I see the connection come into my endpoint, I see `http://localhost/null HTTP/1.1" 200` and I expect to see `http://localhost/product`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll do it in https://github.com/zohararad/sails-rest/pull/21, but the finally url was http://localhost/products because I use underscore inflections in my changes.